# Objective-c How to Check and Compare String by position

Tags: objective-c, string, compare, asihttprequest

I'm use ASIHTTPRequest Library

I'm have String to check is  "http://" or "https://"

My TextField is "www.Hello.com" <- it not has "http://" or "https://"

How to check the position 1-7 in "www.Hello.com"

Thank you kindly

Comment: If your string doesn't start with "http://", the first seven characters will be "www.Hel" — is that the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the http or https in your string using NSRange option.

```
NSString *string = @"Your String";
if ([string rangeOfString:@"http"].location == NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"string does not contain http");
} else {
  NSLog(@"string contains http");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSString has a method `substringWithRange:` that would be useful to you.

```
if ([[myString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,7)] isEqualToString:@"http://"]) {
    // do something
}
```

Also note that NSURL has a `scheme` property.  So you could convert to an NSURL and check:

```
if ([[[NSURL urlWithString:myString] scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"]) {
    // do something
}
```